# A faster way to combine two SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I would like to give it a try and ask about my codes on here from now on to see if there are improvement for'em

this code is supposed to combine two sql tables into one.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id < $lastpost AND position = submitter order by id DESC LIMIT 5) t1 JOIN (SELECT username, firstname, lastname, avatar FROM users) t2 ON t1.submitter = t2.username
```

I was thinking that there might be a better way doing it using union or anything faster, if I'm even right about what I'm saying.

Comment: Why the sub-query, and why write a union-like query without the `UNION` keyword

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Code in the question should not be edited. If you feel that the code formatting needs work, you can point it out in an answer. ([Example](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46875/9357))

Comment: @200_success Ok, noted :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that each post has exactly one submitter, this is a more natural formulation of the query.

```
SELECT posts.*
     , users.username
     , users.firstname
     , users.lastname
     , users.avatar
    FROM posts
        JOIN users
            ON posts.submitter = users.username
    WHERE
        posts.id < $lastpost
        AND posts.position = posts.submitter
    ORDER BY posts.id DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

However, its performance is likely to be similar to your original query.  To investigate performance issues, run `EXPLAIN SELECT` to help you verify that the necessary indexes are in place.